# Can't create SimpleImage class

Tags: php

I installed [SimpleImage](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage) using `require_once("SimpleImage.php");`.

If it's implemented, why does it say the class doesn't exist?

```
<?php
 require_once('SimpleImage.php');
 $image = new SimpleImage();
?>
```

> Fatal error: Class 'SimpleImage' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\empty\index.php on line 3

Comment: Where have you placed `SimpleImage.php'` file ? Is is in the same directory as `index.php` lies in ?

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleImage` is in the namespace **abeautifulsite** - either your code needs to operate in the same one, or you can use the full classpath. The latter is a lot cleaner, in my opinion.

```
$image = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage();
```

Comment: As shown in the very first example on the project's site: https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage

Comment: Didn't notice this. Thanks for explaining, works like a charm ;)